# Low pass filtering not working as expected

Tags: matlab, filter

The following Matlab script is for filtering a signal consisting of a 50 Hz and 120 Hz sine. I am calculating the frequnecy in rad/s as Fp= (2*PI * 30)/1000=0.184. 
I have kept fp=0.184 and fst=0.185, as I want to filter out both 50 hz and 120 Hz. 
But when I am plotting the FFT of the output of the filter, what I am getting is a sine at 50 Hz. Why this 50Hz sine is coming even after filtering?

Ideally there should not be any peak in the plot.

**Before filtering** 
[image]

**after filtering**
[image]

```
Fs = 1000;                    % Sampling frequency
T = 1/Fs;    % Sample time
L = 1000;                     % Length of signal
t =(0:L-1)*T;                % Time vector 
x = 0.7*sin(2*pi*50*t) + sin(2*pi*120*t);  % Sum of a 50 Hz sinusoid and a 120 Hz sinusoid %
y = x + 2*randn(size(t));     % Sinusoids plus noise

y = x ;

plot(Fs*t(1:50),y(1:50));title('Signal');xlabel('time (milliseconds)')

%pause;

NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L); % Next power of 2 from length of y
Y = fft(y,NFFT)/L; f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);

% Plot single-sided amplitude spectrum.
plot(f,2*abs(Y(1:NFFT/2+1))) 
title('Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of y(t)');xlabel('Frequency(Hz)');ylabel('|Y(f)|')


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       Now let us see Low Pass Filtering of this signal  
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Fp= (2*pi * 30)/1000; %=0.184 %only frequncies less than 30Hz will be passed  

d=fdesign.lowpass('Fp,Fst,Ap,Ast',0.184,0.185,2,60);

designmethods(d);

Hd = design(d,'equiripple'); fvtool(Hd);

Filterd_Output = filter(Hd,y);

NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L); % Next power of 2 from length of y
Filtered_Freq = fft(Filterd_Output,NFFT)/L;
f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);

% Plot single-sided amplitude spectrum.
plot(f,2*abs(Filtered_Freq(1:NFFT/2+1)))
title('Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of Low Pass Filtered_Output')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');ylabel('|Filtered_Freq_Amplitude|')
```

**Update**
As suggested I compared the original spectrum with the filterd one. This explains me a lot. But is there any way so that I can reduce this spike at 50 Hz further?

Comment: Have you compared to a before graph? The 'peak' magnitude is only 0.035, maybe that's comparable to the original size but also maybe it's a lot smaller and thus filtered?

Comment: Also your code is hard to read, please add some line breaks, its difficult to see what's code and what's comments

Comment: @gpuguy you really should know better

Comment: @Rasman please send me a link describing editting

Comment: Either move the pole of your filter to a lower frequency or create a higher order filter. Is 50Hz below your -3db point? I mean, it is reduced by 95%, that's pretty good. But also, your signal seems empty?

Comment: Also consider using a notch filter if you are only targeting 50Hz

Comment: @gpuguy it's available when you hit the orange question box: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You incorrectly specify the normalized frequencies for the filter. Matlab assumes the frequency to be in [0, 1], not in [0, pi].

Replace

```
d=fdesign.lowpass('Fp,Fst,Ap,Ast',0.184,0.185,2,60);
```

with

```
d=fdesign.lowpass('Fp,Fst,Ap,Ast', 2*30/Fs, 2*35/Fs,2,60);
```

or alternatively

```
d=fdesign.lowpass('Fp,Fst,Ap,Ast', 30, 35,2,60, Fs);
```

and it should work as expected.